# How to run my code again when the player answers?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
import random
def playGame(errmsg):
    done = 0
    while(done != 1):
        try:
            SInput = input("What is the lowest number?")
            LInput = input("What is the highest number?")
            s = int(SInput)
            l = int(LInput)
            if s > l:
                print(errmsg)
        except:
            print(errmsg)
        done = 1
    while(done != 2):
        try:
            answer = random.randint(s, l)
            replyInput = input("Guess the number!(%d - %d)" % (s, l))
            reply = int(replyInput)
            if reply < answer:
                print("Your guess is too small! Please guess a larger number!")
            elif reply > answer:
                print("Your guess is too large! Please guess a smaller number!")
            elif reply == answer:
                print("You guessed the correct number!")
                done = 2
        except:
            print(errmsg)
    playAgain = input("Do you want to play again?(Y/N)")
    if playAgain == "Y":
        done = 0
    elif playAgain == "N":
        print("Bye!")
playGame("Please input a valid number")
```

How can I make the code restart and generate another number?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a line into your function that returns a True or False for whether they want to play again. Then where you call the 'playgame' function put that in a while loop that breaks when the function returns false.

Apologies for brevity, sent from mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can add `playGame("Please input a valid number")` in the if condition where you check if user has responded in Yes.

```
if playAgain == "Y":
    done = 0
    playGame("Please input a valid number")
```

It will recursively run until you input `N`.

I would also suggest you add `answer = random.randint(s, l)` piece of code outside the while loop, as each run of the loop would generate a random choice and user might not be able to guess it correctly as your hints might not be valid for the next iteration. Do something like:

```
answer = random.randint(s, l)
    while(done != 2):
```